# htaccess - rewrite to docroot index.html without redirect

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need to construct a `RewriteRule` to have the docroot's `index.html` file handle all requests made to a folder named: `doc`.

Here's what I have:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteRule ^doc/(.*) index.html  [DPI,NS]
</IfModule>
```

I've added the `[DPI,NS]` flags to try and force this rule to only do this once, but, I think I'm missing something really obvious because it goes into a nested request loop, forever adding subsequent requests to the original request path -even without the flags.

When I visit: `apache.dev:/doc/hello.htm`, here's a snippet of the subsequent request log:

> /doc/lib/lib/gui/lib/lib/gui/gui/lib/css/base.css

-which is weird, because ALL those 3-letter folder-names are directly in the docroot - and have no sub-directories in them.

When I specify the target path **absolutely** (starting with i.e: `http://`), it works, however, I get a `302` (redirect) - which is not what I want at all.

When I specify the path **relatively** to a sub-folder where I put this index.html file, then it works perfectly.

#### Question:

How do I force this to behave the way I need to (as with relative path) referring it to the docroot's "index.html" file - without redirect?

Any answer/comment will be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: DPI is probably causing issues. Does the simplest case with `[L]` work?  `RewriteRule ^doc/(.*) index.html  [L]`  Be sure to test this in a new private browsing window. Browsers may aggressively cache previous redirects which makes it really difficult to debug mod_rewrite.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski :: thanks, just tried that, no luck. I replaced the whole line as suggested, saved, tested, hard-refreshed; still goes into redirect/rewrite _grow-loop_.

Comment: If you comment out `RewriteBase`, does the loop still happen?  Are there any other rewrite rules?

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski :: thanks, just tried that, in new window; still the same. the only other directives I have is `ErrorDocument 404 /lib/dbug.htm`; but the file I just tried does in fact exist  :(

Comment: Okay, I've commented out everything except that ifmodule block - with 2  lines inside; including `RewriteEngine On` ... still the same ;(

Comment: Wait - if you disabled `RewriteEngine On` and still had a rewritten result, there is something suspect happening, such as an earlier rewrite getting in the way at the server level, or your browser is caching an old faulty redirect.  If that was removed, then no rewriting should happen at all. Is this .htaccess in the root directory? Is there an .htaccess in the doc/ directory?

Comment: Sorry, I may have worded it wrong. I kept `RewriteEngine On` and below that the `RewriteRule ^doc/(.*) index.html [L]` line; so, in total is 2 lines.  Yes, this `.htaccess` file is in the `docroot` and no other .htaccess exist anywhere else at all in this project.

Comment: I found the problem, oh brother, it's the way you reference resources from within HTML.  If you have: `<script src="some/file.js">`, then the request will look in the current `document.href` directory for `some/file.js`; however; if you refer it like: `<script src="/some/file.js">` (note, it starts with a `/`) -then it will actually look in the docroot; and not append subsequent requests to the current href dir, which works just fine.. omg, can't believe I fell for this old gotcha :D

Comment: @argon Please post your comment as an answer and accept it, so everybody can see this question is solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why it generates an infinite request-loop in growing the path is because of the way you reference a path in the handler, if the handler is client-side.

If you have: `<script src="some/file.js">`, then the request will look in the current `document.href` path's directory for some/file.js

If you refer it like: `<script src="/some/file.js">` (note, it starts with a `/`) -then it will actually look in the `docroot`; and not append subsequent requests to the current href dir, -which works just fine.